# Is it ok to have a 2 inch piece of vinyl at the end of the row against wall

Tags: vinyl-flooring, vinyl

Is it ok to have 2 inch long piece of vinyl laminate at end of run against wall

Comment: Aesthetically, very probably not. Are your concerns around maintenance, movement, tear? Are you asking if the installer did a poor job? You might provide a picture for clarity.

Comment: Most flooring/ceiling covering will not be a perfect fit to the room.  Usually recommended to have both ends/sides equal.  If flooring comes in 4 inch wide pieces and have 2 inches on one side, then start with a one inch wide piece and end with one wide piece.

Comment: @crip659 And you don't decide this half way through the job.. lol

Comment: @JACK  That is when the fun starts.

Comment: Usually not, you ned to allow for thermal expansion

Comment: Forgot to add 'inch' after the one in my comment.  Should read 'end with one inch wide piece.'

Comment: @crip659 ... or start with 3 inch wide piece and end with a 3 inch wide piece ... it would look better